# Can not boot into Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

I am New to Ubuntu. My System has got Windows 7 Prof 64 bit.

3 Hard disks are connected.2 tb 2tb and 500gb.
in 500gb 3 partitions are there.

in 1. windows7 2. ubuntu and 3. empty.

I installed ubuntu first time and when system got rebooted windows 7 appeared. I thought installation was not correct. again I formatted and installed. 
Now I am getting only ubuntu.

Please help me to solve the problem.

So many of software’s are there in windows7.

I tried windows 7 cd to repair. it recognises os but when it is unable to boot.

Another problem is I am unable to Shutdown ubuntu. Every time I shutdown automatically it restarts.
I have been switching off power.

Urgent. If in India Please provide Phone contact I would like to contact.

Thank you

Swami Adityananda

Comment: Open a terminal in Ubuntu and type `sudo update-grub` see if it solves your problem. If not open gparted tool in Ubuntu and see if Windows 7 disk as a boot flag. You can also try [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool. Post back with the result.

Comment: I tried Sudo upda-grub. I am getting Grub menu now. I don't no why windows 7 coming 2 times. I removed other harddisk later I am getting only 1. I chose that but windows is not starting. Is there any method to solve this through ubuntu. I tried through Windows 7 disk. It recognises windows7 but unable to solve. please help.....

Comment: can you try boot repair tool?

Comment: Where do i get boot repair in ubuntu?

Comment: see this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I havn't understood this. Please guide step by step. I will now only.

Comment: To install it follow the instructions under the heading "2nd option : install Boot-Repair in Ubuntu" and to use it follow the instructions "Recommended repair" under in the "Using Boot-repair" in the above link.

Comment: I am trying 2nd option.

Comment: all 3 commands done. accepted recommended repair. it says it can be done through live use or so... what shall i do? shall i boot from usb. and try uubuntu or what else. please guide..

Comment: it says in terminal adityananda@adityananda-desktop:~$ 
(gksudo:13652): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_value_free: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

Comment: Please use this software in a live-session (live-CD or live-USB). This will enable this feature.

Comment: How to do this?

Comment: Dear Ron I am Waiting for your guidance

Comment: Burn it into a usb as given in the "1st option : get a disk including Boot-Repair". Enable boot from usb from BIOS.

Comment: How to burn boot-repair to usb.  just copying is ok?

Comment: Nope, you need to use tools such as [Unetbootin](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/03/how-to-create-bootable-linux-usb-drive.html). Follow the instructions at http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/

Comment: internet slow. is it necessary to download 613mb iso file. only Boot repair is it available.

Comment: what is use of boot-repair program in ubuntu. I have intalled ubuntu 15.04. and also boot repair. 613 mb file has got which os? is it compatiable with 15.04? in Unetbootin I don't see 15.04 os name to Burn. Please guide